# Flash - Password login fail on Ctrl+Enter keypress

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, password-protection

I'm using Flash CS4 and AS 3.0

I'm trying to add a login for running my flash movie.
When the user clicks the login button, the text of the password field is authenticated, which allows `gotoAndPlay(2)` .

But the problem is both in my `.swf` and my projector `.exe` i can easily jump the login frame by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a listener on enter frame and check if the user is authenticated.
if not, send him back to the login frame.

Answer (score 0):

Avi's answer will work, I think, but it would be good to remember to remove that listener after you've confirmed they're authenticated, so that it doesn't keep checking after you're sure they've logged in.